# bootstrap button toggle to upward

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button which will display a dropdown menu after clicked. But I want toggle to upward. Is it possible?

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="/images/icon_happy.gif" alt="" /> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bootstrap has a `dropup` class.

```
 <div class="dropup">
   //put your button and ul here
 </div>
```

See [bootstrap dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example) And here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un23moLp/)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/mhtb26en/ . I think you will need to intercept dropdown open and close events to change the style accordingly

```
span.rotate {
    transform : rotate(180deg);
}
```